# Ethernet transformer TD/TX sides

Tags: transformer, ethernet, rj45

I’m curious as to the side the TD and TX side go to on an Ethernet transformer.

I have drawn this schematic below and the datasheet for the Ethernet transformer hip is attached as well but I’m not sure if my schematic is correct in relation to the datasheet. Basically if I need to swap the TX side for the TD for connection to the Ethernet connector (or if it doesn’t matter).

My schematic:

[image: My schematic]

From the HC-027 datasheet:

[image: HC-027 datasheet diagram]

Comment: What are you curious about -- which side it should go to? The schematic appears correct as far as TD/TX.

Comment: Other comments: should pin 4 not be biased as well? Should pins 9/10 have Bob Smith termination resistors to `ETH` into the single capacitor (C29)? Should a single TVS be used per pair, not combined for both pairs?

Comment: Your first point on td/tx. If it was correct which was my main concern. 

As for as the other points, yes possibly re the term resistors and a tvs per pair. I’ve seen this schematic used before and just wanted to recreate it. I imagine there may be a better way.

Comment: Just a comment about J2: either it's numbered in a strange way or it's not the usual ethernet connector.  Or I suppose a very strange wiring of the usual connector.

Comment: J2 is just a 4 wire Ethernet breakout. I just wanted to be able to run Ethernet over 4 wires to a small device a few inches away. Both are powered electrically from the same source.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet does not say that there is anything different in the two internal transformers, so a relatively good assumption is that they can be swapped. Ask the manufacturer for confirmation or change to a part which does mention how the transformers can be used.

However the circuit does not look like a proper Ethernet design. It will blow up the ESD protector if you connect that to passive PoE source. And that is not the only issue. I recommend reading the data sheet and application notes of the PHY you are using.

Comment: Thanks for that! It is generally only plugged straight into a computer for access. The company that makes this chip is no longer in business and the datasheet is lacking (it’s being used for known compatibility reasons to the host device).